# I want open marketplace with specific app after clicking button

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want open marketplace with specific app after clicking button, and I can't find any solution for that. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the [`MarketDetailTask`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.tasks.marketplacedetailtask) class in your button's "Tap" event handler. Just insert the ID of the app that you want to display below.

Here's an example how:

```cs
using Microsoft.Phone.Tasks;

MarketplaceDetailTask marketplaceDetailTask = new MarketplaceDetailTask();
marketplaceDetailTask.ContentIdentifier = "app-id-goes-here";
marketplaceDetailTask.ContentType = MarketplaceContentType.Applications;
marketplaceDetailTask.Show();
```